# How to get the status of the production server symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

When starting the server locally I executed the command `symfony server:prod` using the [Symfony Local Web Server](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/symfony_server.html) which gives me to understand that I changed the state of the server environment to production.

Since then, each time I run the local server, it launches in `prod` environment even if I define a `APP_ENV=dev` environment variable.

How can I switch back to the environment defined in my `.env` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Quick answer

Use `symfony server:prod --off`

## Explanations

By default, the web server will read your Symfony `.env` files to know which environment to use (using the `APP_ENV` key).

The command `symfony server:prod` will force the server to launch the `prod` environment without considering your environment variables.

To disable this and keep using your environment variables, just use `symfony server:prod --off`